# removing all hash tag and words following it in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex to remove hashtags:

```
preg_replace('/#([\w-]+)/i', '$1', $string);
```

and say I have the following string:

```
Top idr 160\nDisc 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs \n#onlineshop#lalashop88#jualanku#jualansis#olshop#baju#dress#import#bkk#bkkfashion#bangkok#celana#hotpants#goodquality#jumpsuit#bustier#pants#clothes#indoshop#indonesiashop#jualansis#medan#medanshop#trusted#trustedolshop#trustedshop#goorder#gofollow
```

how do I remove it such that I get this string in the end:

```
Top idr 160\nDisc 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs \n
```

notice that the hashtags aren't separated by a space, but if it were separated by a space I would also want this regex to work

Here's another test case:

```
Top idr 160\nDisc #testing 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs
```

should transform it into

```
Top idr 160\nDisc 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without regex using a simple function like this:

```
function getCleanString($sourceStr, $delimiter = '#') {
    $sourceStrArr = explode($delimiter, $sourceStr);
    return !empty($sourceStrArr[0]) ? $sourceStrArr[0] : $sourceStr;
}
```

Usage:

```
$sourceStr = 'Top idr 160\nDisc 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs \n#onlineshop#lalashop88#jualanku#jualansis#olshop#baju#dress#import#bkk#bkkfashion#bangkok#celana#hotpants#goodquality#jumpsuit#bustier#pants#clothes#indoshop#indonesiashop#jualansis#medan#medanshop#trusted#trustedolshop#trustedshop#goorder#gofollow';

var_dump(getCleanString($sourceStr));
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work, if the string is Top idr 160\nDisc #testing 5rbu\/pcs pembelian di atas 4pcs. then it would return me Top idr 160\nDisc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `/#.+?\b/`, matches `#` followed by one or more characters and terminates at the first word boundary. Depending on what characters are allowed in the hashtags you are stripping that might be enough.

```
preg_replace('/#.+?\b/', '', $string);
```

If the hastags contain things like periods or dashes, you might need to use something like `/#[\w\-.]+/` where `\w\-.` is the possible hashtag charset (`\w` being `A-Za-z0-9` and `_`, so those as well as `.` and `-` (as pointed out in the comment below, `-` needs to be escaped inside character groups).

```
preg_replace('/#[\w\-.]+/', '', $string);
```

Although if you don't understand regex, maybe solving it by string manipulation would be a better option, so you understand your code fully.

Comment: `-` is a special character in a character class, you need to escape it by putting it at the end: `[\w.-]`, to match a literal hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
preg_replace("/#(.*)$/i", "", $input_lines);
```

Replaces #.... with empty string. It allows only spaces between tags, not carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove **everything** following a '#' from the string then

```
/#.*/i
```

Should work.

Comment: I want to remove #string essentially

Comment: Then yes I don't believe it needs to be any more complicated then the above e.g. `preg_replace("/#.*/i", "", $input_lines);`

Comment: what you did essentially removes everything after #string, check my examples in my original post

Comment: Ah ok that's clearer, in that case I would go with the answer by rvalvik